# Strange behavior caused by cygwin, bash, sed and export

Tags: bash, sed, cygwin

I'm sorry. I was so bothered by this problem that I didn't go to bed until 3.am. My brain was a flur at that time and the old problem description was a mess. I have rewritten the problem description and deleted the old one.

---

I've found a strange behavior about cygwin, bash, sed and export.
Save the following code into a file, say /r/a.sh

```
echo PATH is $PATH
echo the sed in use is `which sed`

echo 1 | sed 's|1|22|g'

result=`echo 1 | sed 's|1|22|g'`
echo \`xxx\` without export
echo the result is \"$result\"
echo \`xxx\` with export
export result=`echo 1 | sed 's|1|22|g'`
echo the result is \"$result\"
echo \$\(xxx\) without export
result="$(echo 1 | sed 's|1|22|g')"
echo the result is \"$result\"
echo \$\(xxx\) with export
export result="$(echo 1 | sed 's|1|22|g')"
echo the result is \"$result\"

read
```

The expected results are 22 for all four cases. And that's true for most enviroments I have tried, such as Debian, zsh, and running bash in conemu. In conemu, the result is:

```
PATH is /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/d/PortableAppsLocal/ConEmu/ConEmu/Scripts:/d/PortableAppsLocal/ConEmu:/d/PortableAppsLocal/ConEmu/ConEmu:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/MPI-RT/4.1.3.045/em64t/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/MPI-RT/4.1.3.045/ia32/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/GNU/GnuPG/pub:/c/Program Files/IBM/Bluemix/bin:/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/runtime/win64:/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/bin:/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/c/Program Files (x86)/Subversion/bin:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/OpenVPN/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/STMicroelectronics/STM32 ST-LINK Utility/ST-LINK Utility:/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/d/Cloud/Win+R:/usr/bin:/d/Python/Python36:/d/Python/Python36/Scripts:/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox:/d/PortableAppsLocal/bin:/d/Python/Python27:/d/Python/Python27/Scripts:/c/Program Files (x86)/Subversion/bin:/c/Program Files/LLVM/bin:/d/gccarm/bin:/c/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_172/bin:/d/lint:/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin
the sed in use is /usr/bin/sed
22
`xxx` without export
the result is "22"
`xxx` with export
the result is "22"
$(xxx) without export
the result is "22"
$(xxx) with export
the result is "22"
```

However, if I run it by D:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login /r/a.sh, the result is

```
PATH is /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/MPI-RT/4.1.3.045/em64t/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/MPI-RT/4.1.3.045/ia32/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/GNU/GnuPG/pub:/c/Program Files/IBM/Bluemix/bin:/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/runtime/win64:/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/bin:/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/c/Program Files (x86)/Subversion/bin:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/OpenVPN/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/STMicroelectronics/STM32 ST-LINK Utility/ST-LINK Utility:/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/d/Cloud/Win+R:/usr/bin:/d/Python/Python36:/d/Python/Python36/Scripts:/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox:/d/PortableAppsLocal/bin:/d/Python/Python27:/d/Python/Python27/Scripts:/c/Program Files (x86)/Subversion/bin:/c/Program Files/LLVM/bin:/d/gccarm/bin:/c/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_172/bin:/d/lint:/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin
the sed in use is /usr/bin/sed
22
`xxx` without export
the result is ""
`xxx` with export
the result is "22"
$(xxx) without export
the result is ""
$(xxx) with export
the result is ""
```

I have also tried to use absolute path of sed.

```
echo run with absolute path /sed/bin

echo 1 | sed 's|1|22|g'

result=`echo 1 | /bin/sed 's|1|22|g'`
echo \`xxx\` without export
echo the result is \"$result\"
echo \`xxx\` with export
export result=`echo 1 | /bin/sed 's|1|22|g'`
echo the result is \"$result\"
echo \$\(xxx\) without export
result="$(echo 1 | /bin/sed 's|1|22|g')"
echo the result is \"$result\"
echo \$\(xxx\) with export
export result="$(echo 1 | /bin/sed 's|1|22|g')"
echo the result is \"$result\"

read
```

The result is still

```
run with absolute path /sed/bin
22
`xxx` without export
the result is ""
`xxx` with export
the result is "22"
$(xxx) without export
the result is ""
$(xxx) with export
the result is ""
```

I have also tried run it without --login, the results are the same.

In conclusion, there are four cases, and only export result=`xxx` works as expected.

---

I tried add set -x at the begining of the script, the results are

```
C:\Users\user>D:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login /r/a.sh
+ echo PATH is /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Program Files '(x86)/Intel/MPI-RT/4.1.3.045/em64t/bin:/c/Program' Files '(x86)/Intel/MPI-RT/4.1.3.045/ia32/bin:/c/Program' Files '(x86)/Common' Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/c/Program Files '(x86)/GNU/GnuPG/pub:/c/Program' Files/IBM/Bluemix/bin:/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/runtime/win64:/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/bin:/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/c/Program Files '(x86)/Subversion/bin:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program' Files/OpenVPN/bin:/c/Program Files '(x86)/STMicroelectronics/STM32' ST-LINK Utility/ST-LINK Utility:/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/d/Cloud/Win+R:/usr/bin:/d/Python/Python36:/d/Python/Python36/Scripts:/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox:/d/PortableAppsLocal/bin:/d/Python/Python27:/d/Python/Python27/Scripts:/c/Program Files '(x86)/Subversion/bin:/c/Program' Files/LLVM/bin:/d/gccarm/bin:/c/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_172/bin:/d/lint:/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin
PATH is /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/MPI-RT/4.1.3.045/em64t/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/MPI-RT/4.1.3.045/ia32/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/GNU/GnuPG/pub:/c/Program Files/IBM/Bluemix/bin:/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/runtime/win64:/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/bin:/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/c/Program Files (x86)/Subversion/bin:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/OpenVPN/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/STMicroelectronics/STM32 ST-LINK Utility/ST-LINK Utility:/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/d/Cloud/Win+R:/usr/bin:/d/Python/Python36:/d/Python/Python36/Scripts:/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox:/d/PortableAppsLocal/bin:/d/Python/Python27:/d/Python/Python27/Scripts:/c/Program Files (x86)/Subversion/bin:/c/Program Files/LLVM/bin:/d/gccarm/bin:/c/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_172/bin:/d/lint:/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin

C:\Users\user>D:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login /r/a.sh
+ echo PATH is /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Program Files '(x86)/Intel/MPI-RT/4.1.3.045/em64t/bin:/c/Program' Files '(x86)/Intel/MPI-RT/4.1.3.045/ia32/bin:/c/Program' Files '(x86)/Common' Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/c/Program Files '(x86)/GNU/GnuPG/pub:/c/Program' Files/IBM/Bluemix/bin:/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/runtime/win64:/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/bin:/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/c/Program Files '(x86)/Subversion/bin:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program' Files/OpenVPN/bin:/c/Program Files '(x86)/STMicroelectronics/STM32' ST-LINK Utility/ST-LINK Utility:/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/d/Cloud/Win+R:/usr/bin:/d/Python/Python36:/d/Python/Python36/Scripts:/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox:/d/PortableAppsLocal/bin:/d/Python/Python27:/d/Python/Python27/Scripts:/c/Program Files '(x86)/Subversion/bin:/c/Program' Files/LLVM/bin:/d/gccarm/bin:/c/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_172/bin:/d/lint:/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin
PATH is /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/MPI-RT/4.1.3.045/em64t/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/MPI-RT/4.1.3.045/ia32/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/GNU/GnuPG/pub:/c/Program Files/IBM/Bluemix/bin:/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/runtime/win64:/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/bin:/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/c/Program Files (x86)/Subversion/bin:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/OpenVPN/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/STMicroelectronics/STM32 ST-LINK Utility/ST-LINK Utility:/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/d/Cloud/Win+R:/usr/bin:/d/Python/Python36:/d/Python/Python36/Scripts:/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox:/d/PortableAppsLocal/bin:/d/Python/Python27:/d/Python/Python27/Scripts:/c/Program Files (x86)/Subversion/bin:/c/Program Files/LLVM/bin:/d/gccarm/bin:/c/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_172/bin:/d/lint:/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin
++ which sed
+ echo the sed in use is /usr/bin/sed
the sed in use is /usr/bin/sed
+ echo 1
+ sed 's|1|22|g'
22
+ result=
+ echo '`xxx`' without export
`xxx` without export
+ echo the result is '""'
the result is ""
+ echo '`xxx`' with export
`xxx` with export
++ echo 1
++ sed 's|1|22|g'
+ export result=22
+ result=22
+ echo the result is '"22"'
the result is "22"
+ echo '$(xxx)' without export
$(xxx) without export
+ result=
+ echo the result is '""'
the result is ""
+ echo '$(xxx)' with export
$(xxx) with export
+ export result=
+ result=
+ echo the result is '""'
the result is ""
```

Comment: run a bash login shell to properly set the PATH

Comment: Can you please edit the question and copy-paste the exact, unabbreviated output including any error messages? There's [a lot of information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) to be had from seemingly unimportant changes, so it's important to copy-paste and not transcribe by hand.

Comment: You're setting `PATH` to just `/bin` because you use `;` instead of `:`. Furthermore, all your `echo` commands should print something like `a = "22"`, with spaces, so it looks like your actual output shown here isn't really what you're seeing.

Comment: Also, typo on the last  line, `$c` instead of `$d`?

Comment: Thank you for your replies and sorry for the previous mess description. I have modified it. @thatotherguy, the newly pasted results are the exact, unabbreviated output. There are no error messages given.

Comment: I can't replicate this problem in Cygwin under Windows 10, I'm afraid. Running the script from a Windows `cmd.exe` prompt using `c:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login` gives the expected output. Is it worth putting `set -x` at the top of the script to see what exactly `bash` is running?

Comment: @Jon I added set -x at the begin, and ran it from cmd.exe. The result has been appended to the description. It seems in the first case ( with ` `), sed is run but the result is not assigned to the variable. In the second case (with $( )), sed is not run at all.

Comment: @iuradz That is really weird! Is there a chance you have character encoding problems? Does `od -c a.sh` show any funny characters in the script?

Comment: @Jon I'm afraid not, and it's not a problem of EOL. The most weird part is that it's normal under conemu.

Comment: @iuradz This is clasping at straws, but could we have the output of `env` and `set`, please? Is this an `IFS` problem or something?

Comment: @Jon I have appended the output of env and set. Please have a look at them.

Comment: I have deleted the output of set and env because of privacy concern.

Comment: I suspect you have a mixture of environments. Simplify by ensuring your `%PATH%` in dos is simply your cygwin bin dir followed by your system32 folder (in a _cmd_ shell: `set PATH=D:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Windows\System32`). Next run your script without an absolute path to _bash_ (in the same _cmd_ shell: `bash -x c:\r\sh.sh`)

Comment: @bobbogo I don't know what happened to the system in the past two weeks, but the problem disappeared and I can no longer dulicated it. Thank you for your reply.